# Convert binary to text, for writing to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to convert a binary field to text so that I can output it to a file.  The contents are XML.  So far I have...

```
File.open("public/test.txt", 'w') { |file| file.write(@report.catalog_xml) }
```

The error complains about "\xAC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8.  I have tried the Marshal, and Yaml dumps, but still cannot get the plain text as an output

Comment: try `wb` instead of `w`..

Comment: please show output of `puts @report.catalog_xml.encoding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the encoding of the target file to match that of the data source.  You can determine that as follows assuming `#catalog_xml` returns a string:

```
@report.catalog_xml.encoding.name // => (e.g. ASCII-8BIT)
```

With that knowledge, just specify it when you write to the file:

```
File.open("public/test.txt", "w:ASCII-8BIT") { |file| file.write(@report.catalog_xml) }
```

You could even interpolate the value:

```
File.open("public/test.txt", "w:#{@report.catalog_xml.encoding.name}") { |file| file.write(@report.catalog_xml) }
```